# android MalformedURL exception

Tags: java, android, xml

I am getting an error: error opening trace file: no such file or directory
java.net.malformedURLexception: protocol not found: cars.xml

I want to create a xml file in Internal storage and show the car_name and car_model in a listview.

my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView listView;
Button createCar;
String XML_CONTENT = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><cars><car><carMake></carMake><carModel></carModel><fuelType></fuelType><carYear></carYear><carColor></carColor><engineHp></engineHp><engineCcm></engineCcm></car></cars>";
static String myXML = "cars.xml";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] myCars = null;
    fileCreate();

    ParseXML parseXML= new ParseXML(); 
    myCars = parseXML.giveCars(myXML);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    if (myCars.length == 0 || myCars == null) 
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your car list is empty. Please create a new car!", 8000).show();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view_row, R.id.textView1, myCars);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}

private void fileCreate() {

    try {
        FileOutputStream os = openFileOutput(myXML, MODE_PRIVATE);
        os.write(XML_CONTENT.getBytes());
        os.close();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NON created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("ReadNWrite, fileCreate()", "Exception e = " + e);
    }
}
```

the giveCars function:

```
public String[] giveCars(String cars) {

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(cars);

        String[] carsInFile = null;
        NodeList myCars = doc.getElementsByTagName("car");
        Node myCar;
        NodeList spec;

        for (int i = 0; i < myCars.getLength(); i++) {
            myCar = myCars.item(i);
            spec = myCar.getChildNodes();
            carsInFile[i] = spec.item(0).toString() + " "
                    + spec.item(1).toString();
        }
        return carsInFile;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        android.util.Log.e("tag", "", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

If run this functions in an simple java project everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably having errors in your openFileOutput function, but I don't know why. Here is a tip to make it better. You can save and array of the object **car** instead of saving a xml file. It optimizes your code. Look at this function *(the object needs to be Serializable)*:

```
public static void saveFile(String filename, Object object) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = AplicationHelper.getAppContext()
                    .openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(object);
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

and to load it, you have this function:

```
public static Object loadFile(String filename) {
    Object object = null;
    try {
        Log.i("AppData.Load", "Trying to load file " + filename);
        FileInputStream fis = ApplicationHelper.getAppContext()
                .openFileInput(filename);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        object = is.readObject();
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("AppData.Load", "Exception " + e);
        return null;
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        return null; // when on desktop mode
    }
    return object;
}
```

And you can load the array from the file directly to your arrayadapter easily

Comment: Sorry, I pasted it wrong, now you have edited. =) Works fine here

Comment: aplicationHelper is a class you wrote, or? Error: AplicationHelper cannot be resolved

Comment: it's just a class that I wrote to get the Context wherever the application is. If you are putting this code in any activity, you can get the Application Context. Else, just add a Context parameter and pass it though.